# Wait while task running? / Jump next line when task done?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

I saw a lot of topics about powershell + waiting for process ending, but somehow its not working for me. I have this:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

Add-SPSolution sol.wsp

Install-SPSolution -identity $sol -GACDeployment

Install-SPFeature "feature"
```

What Im trying to do is to add a new Sharepoint (2010) solution, then Im trying to install a solution and finally Im trying to install feature.

The last one is failing, because the installation of the solution takes somehow longer but he is already trying to install the feature. I get the error `Install-SPFeature : Failed to find the XML file at location` if I start the script again the feature can be installed. How could I change my script to handle this problem? Ok sure I could use `Start-Sleep -s 2` or something, but thats not the best way. `| Out-Null` or `-Wait` isnt working too. I think thats because the process or whatever it is already done, but windows takes some seconds to realize that the solution is installed. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use Start-Job?

```
$sb = { Install-SPSolution -identity $sol -GACDeployment }
$job = start-job -scriptblock $sb
Wait-Job $job  | Out-Null
$retMsg = Receive-Job $job
```

Comment: Hm with this Im not able to do anything, I get the message: `The term 'Install-SPSolution' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inclu
ded, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-SPSolution:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: It's just because you have to add the snappin inside the scriptblock you start as a job. You call also pass arguments to the job.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet from the deployment script I use:

```
Write-Host "Deploying solution: $SolutionPackageName"
$Solution = Get-SPSolution | ? {($_.Name -eq $SolutionPackageName) -and ($_.Deployed -eq $false)}
Install-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionPackageName -GACDeployment -Confirm:$false -force
$index = 0 
[DateTime] $startingTime = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(2) 
while($Solution.JobExists) 
{ 
    $index++ 
    if($startingTime -lt [DateTime]::Now) 
    { 
        Write-Host "Deployment job: $SolutionPackageName failed. Deployed = $Solution.Deployed, Index = $index"
        break 
    } 
    Write-Host "Deployment job: $SolutionPackageName is still running. Deployed = $Solution.Deployed, Index = $index"
    Start-Sleep -s 5 
    $Solution = Get-SPSolution | ? {$_.Name -eq $SolutionPackageName}
} 
Write-Host "Deploying solution: $SolutionPackageName - Done."
```

Yes, it uses `Start-Sleep`, but I think the script uses it in a smart way by checking when the solution is actually deployed. Personally, I like the feedback on screen to know that the script is not hung. I've never had a case where it's exceeded 2 minutes, but I've definitely had it display up to 10 "still running" messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` option:

```
Start-Process Powershell "Install-SPSolution -identity $sol -GACDeployment" -Wait

Install-SPFeature "feature"
```

Comment: Just realized this may not be suitable in your case due to your need to do a `Add-PSSnapin`. Oh well...